# Get Request object in Struts Action Class

Tags: java, struts2, httprequest

I read two different way to get Request object in any action class of struts which are as below

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get( ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
```

And

```
HttpServletRequest request =  ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

I want to know what is the difference between both of them. Its look like both are same because `ServletActionContext` Class provides us the request object.

Comment: Use the interface instead, even better. The second is easier to mock.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18802952/573032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServletActionContext.getRequest()` [is implemented as](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.1.2/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.java#ServletActionContext.getRequest%28%29)

```
public static HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    return (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(HTTP_REQUEST);
}
```

You either do it directly or call this method. They do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for answer and a link to clarify it.